# Cannot run casperjs with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, casperjs

I installed jenkins as a window service. I create a node to run casperjs. However, the result from the node always says 'casperjs in not internal or external command'. Any experience for this case?

Comment: Have you installed CasperJS and if yes, how? What happens when you type `casperjs --version` in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Install casperjs using node in global, to avoid PATH problem :

`npm install -g phantomjs`
`npm install -g casperjs`

It's just node doesn't recognize the casper command in your current node file location.